# Initialising a vector field in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, vectorization

I'd like to initialize a numpy array to represent a two-dimensional vector field on a 100 x 100 grid of points defined by:

```
import numpy as np
dx = dy = 0.1
nx = ny = 100
x, y =  np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,nx*dx,dx), np.arange(0,ny*dy,dy))
```

The field is a constant-speed circulation about the point cx,cy and I can initialize it OK with regular Python loops:

```
v = np.empty((nx, ny, 2))
cx, cy = 5, 5
s = 2
for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(ny):
        rx, ry = i*dx - cx, j*dy - cy
        r = np.hypot(rx, ry)
        if r == 0:
            v[i,j] = 0,0
            continue
        # (-ry/r, rx/r): the unit vector tangent to the circle centred at (cx,cy), radius r
        v[i,j] = (s * -ry/r, s * rx/r)
```

But when I'm having trouble vectorizing with numpy. The closest I've got is

```
v = np.array([s * -(y-cy) / np.hypot(x-cx, y-cy), s * (x-cx) / np.hypot(x-cx, y-cy)])
v = np.rollaxis(v, 1, 0)
v = np.rollaxis(v, 2, 1)
v[np.isinf(v)] = 0
```

But this isn't equivalent and doesn't give the right answer. What is the correct way to initialize a vector field using numpy?

EDIT: OK - now I'm confused following the suggestion below, I try:

```
vx = s * -(y-cy) / np.hypot(x-cx, y-cy)
vy = s * (x-cx) / np.hypot(x-cx, y-cy)
v = np.dstack((vx, vy))
v[np.isnan(v)] = 0
```

but get a completely different array...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you -- I don't have explicit indices i and j if I'm vectorizing.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your example: `cx = cy= 5, 5` assigns the tuple `(5, 5)` to both `cx` and `cy`. You probably mean `cx, cy = 5, 5`.

Comment: Thanks for that catch! I've fixed it now in my post because it wasn't the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your initial setup:

```
import numpy as np

dx = dy = 0.1
nx = ny = 100
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, nx * dx, dx),
                   np.arange(0, ny * dy, dy))
cx = cy = 5
s = 2
```

You could compute `v` like this:

```
rx, ry = y - cx, x - cy
r = np.hypot(rx, ry)
v2 = s * np.dstack((-ry, rx)) / r[..., None]
v2[np.isnan(v2)] = 0
```

If you're feeling really fancy, you could create `yx` as a 3D array, and broadcast all of the operations over it:

```
# we make these [2,] arrays to broadcast over the last output dimension
c = np.array([5, 5])
s = np.array([-2, 2])

# this creates a [100, 100, 2] mesh, where the last dimension corresponds
# to (y, x)
yx = np.mgrid[0:nx * dx:dx, 0:ny * dy:dy].T

yxdiff = yx - c[None, None, :]
r = np.hypot(yxdiff[..., 0], yxdiff[..., 1])[..., None]
v3 = s[None, None, :] * yxdiff / r
v3[np.isnan(v3)] = 0
```

Check that these both give the same answer as your original code:

```
print np.all(v == v2), np.all(v == v3)
# True, True
```

### Edit

Why `rx, ry = y - cx, x - cy` rather than `rx, ry = x - cx, y - cy`? I agree it's very counterintuitive - the only reason I decided to do it that way was to match the output of your original code.

The issue is that in your grids, consecutive *x* values are actually found in consecutive *columns* of `x`, and consecutive *y* values are found in consecutive *rows* of `y`,  i.e. `x[:, j]` is the *j* th x-value and `y[i, :]` is the *i* th y-value. However, in your inner loop, you are multiplying `dx` by `i`, which is your *row* index, and `dy` by `j`, which is your *column* index. You're therefore flipping the x and y dimensions of your output.

Comment: I accept your solution works... but I don't understand why it's `rx, ry = y - cx, x - cy` and not `rx, ry = x - cx, y - cy`. Isn't this the unit vector from C to R?

Comment: @lauren96 See my update. It's easy to get your dimensions muddled when you're only working with square matrices - it might be helpful to specify different values for `nx` and `ny` to see which dimension corresponds to which in the output.

Comment: Yup - that's it. Thanks, ali_m